# How to I map a storage account in Linux PHP7.2 in PAAS Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Being quite new to Azure, does anyone know how to map a Blob File storage on Linux PHP7.2 box as PAAS ?

I looked at the documentation followed the instruction, but they do not work on my App Service. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux

According to this documentation, Blobfuse needs to be installed in order for this to work.
I cannot install Blobfuse, lsb_release -a does not work (part of the instructions), according to terminal the installed package is linux 4.4.0-128.154.

I can find a Wordpress plugin that uses the Wordpress CLI, but that is not really what I am looking for. (I dont use Wordpress on my site, but I thought the code could give me a hint)

I am just looking for a file share to add store uploaded images.

Has anyone done this before? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to mount a blob container or Azure File share? If blob container, the Blobfuse   doesn't work for you, there are 3rd party tools for blob.https://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup/desktop/linux.aspx

Comment: If you want to mount Azure File share, you could refer to this doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/mount-azure-file-storage-on-linux-using-smb

Comment: If you're using a Web App, you cannot mount an Azure File Share, as it's a sandboxed environment (though you *can* access a file share through the Azure storage SDK or REST API). You can also access blob storage directly (but not as a mounted file drive). Why not just use the storage included with your Web App (it's persistent, unless you delete the web app)

Comment: @GeorgeChen - you cannot mount a file share to an Azure Web App (see my prior comment). Also, this isn't the place to promote 3rd-party tools.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for your feedback, I will look into the Azure storage SDK and the Web App storage and see if I can untilise this.